# Excel: Simulate random sample of integers with given mean, sd, skewness and kurtosis

Tags: excel, statistics

Not sure if this is possible in Excel: I need to simulate a sample of random integers (between 1 and 5) with a fixed mean, standard deviation, skewness and kurtosis.
So far I've only come across =NORM.INV(rand(),MEAN,SD) to generate normally distributed data.

Comment: From which distribution? A normal distribution is defined from 2 moments.

Comment: well yes, originally normal distributed, but with fixed skewness and kurtosis

Comment: U wot? If the distribution is normal then you can't change the skewness and kurtosis once you've decided on the mean and variance. So you need to use a different distribution. But which one?

Comment: yeah that's why the data won't be normally distributed after **after** the change of skewness and kurtosis

Comment: So we're back to the start again. Which *distribution* do you want to draw random numbers from?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've identified the distribution you want, you need to obtain the *quantile* function for that distribution.

If not available directly in Excel, code it up in VBA.

Then you use the function `RAND` and use that as the input to the quantile function.

The resulting random numbers will be distributed correctly.

Answer (score -1):

To generate integer numbers from 1 to 5 You can try this formula:

**=ROUND(RAND()*(5,5-0,5)+0,5;0)**.

They will generate the numbers: 1,2,3,4,5. And every number has a probability to be 0.2.
Normal distribution will generate double type numbers, not integer.